# Create Jquery UI dialog and move top front

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I create a simple Jquery UI dialog and want to put it in front.

```
    var  dialog = $(document.createElement("div"));
    dialog.attr("id","dialog-confirm");
    $( "body" ).append(dialog);


    $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
      resizable: false,
      height: "auto",
      width: 400,
      buttons: {
      "Delete all items": function() {
        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
      },
      Cancel: function() {
        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
      }
    }
});
dialog.dialog("moveToTop");
```

I get this error `Error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'moveToTop'`.

What can I do about that?

Comment: **[Works fine here](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/pwkL2o9m/)**

Answer (score 0):

You technically do not have to append it to the body. The following code will work:

```
$(function() {
  var dialog = $("<div>", {
    id: "dialog-confirm"
  }).dialog({
    resizable: false,
    height: "auto",
    width: 400,
    buttons: {
      "Delete all items": function() {
        $(this).dialog("close");
      },
      Cancel: function() {
        $(this).dialog("close");
      }
    }
  });
  dialog.dialog("moveToTop");
});
```

The `moveToTop` is only needed if you have more than 1 dialog open at a time.